# Falla al momento de capturar la cámara en opencv en Python

Tags: python, opencv, typeerror

Este problema nunca antes me había sucedido. Estoy usando un entorno virtual en **Anaconda** con la ***versión 3.10*** de **python** y ***4.7.0*** de **opencv**. Ya actualice mis drivers de video y comprobé que la cámara esta funcionando con normalidad con **meet** y **teams**.

Este es el código fuente de testeo que uso pero me muestra la cámara en negro.

```py
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)

if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Doesn't exist that camera")

while(cap.isOpened()):
    #Captura frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read();

    #Muestra el resultado de frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

#Cuando todo este hecho cierra el programa
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

al quitar el `cv2.CAP_DSHOW` de la función `VideoCapture` este me lanza un error que es el siguiente.

```
[ WARN:0@12.330] global cap_msmf.cpp:1759 CvCapture_MSMF::grabFrame videoio(MSMF): can't grab frame. Error: -2147483638
```

Espero que alguien tenga una pronta respuesta, de igual forma estaré revisando que otra cosa podría ser el error y actualizaré si ya lo solucione.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que he visto en la documentación de OpenCV, **cv2.CAP_DSHOW** solo **devuelve el numero** de la **cámara** con el backend de DirectShow, el cual es el equivalente a añadir **700** al **índice** de tu **cámara**, en mi caso, tengo para usar el índice **0**, **1** y **2**, y si quiero usar el backend de DirectShow uso el **700**, **701** y **702**, mi recomendación es que intentes probar con **701** o **702**.

Mi conclusión es que **probablemente** tengas una cámara "fantasma" que no está conectada a la PC, ya sea por algún **controlador o un programa** que este haciéndole **creer al sistema** que esa cámara está **conectada** y que es la **predeterminada** y por ende se le asigna el **índice 0**.

Comment: Gracias, encontré que era un problema con mi antivirus ya que tenía como una especie de whitelist para solo permitir acceso a la cámara a ciertos programas del computador.

Me ayudo bastante lo de los índices que mandaste de la cámara, eso fue de mucha ayuda.